# Multi-threading, access UI control

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, invoke, invokerequired

I have a simple app with the usual UI thread and a background worker, in the background worker I need to dynamically create LinkLabels and place them in a FlowLayoutPanel.  In order to do this I need to set the parent of the LinkLabel to the FlowLayoutPanel.

Here is a snippet of code I currently have, however, I get the infamous "Cross-thread operation not valid" on the line 'l.Parent = panel;'

I'm fairly new to multithreaded operations but I thought I did the invoking correctly, but obviously not.  Any Suggestions?

```
LinkLabel l = new LinkLabel();
if (rssFeedPanel.InvokeRequired) {
    FlowLayoutPanel panel = null;
    rssFeedPanel.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { panel = rssFeedPanel; }));
    l.Parent = panel;
}
else
    l.Parent = rssFeedPanel;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to actually set the `Parent` property on the other thread.

```
LinkLabel l = new LinkLabel();
if (rssFeedPanel.InvokeRequired) {
    rssFeedPanel.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate {
        l.Parent = rssFeedPanel;
    }));
}
else
    l.Parent = rssFeedPanel;
```

In general, nearly any operation involving accessing the members of a UI control can only be done from the UI thread. Some obvious exceptions are `Invoke`, `InvokeRequired`, `BeginInvoke`, and some of the methods of the `BackgroundWorker` class.

If you wish for this case, you can also use `BeginInvoke` instead of `Invoke`.

Comment: Just curious, can't you use `if (Dispatcher.Thread == Thread.CurrentThread)` and call `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new EventHandler<T>())` to invoke all controls as opposed to checking whether `InvokeRequired` for each control? Just a brain fart, but if you can, I'm pretty sure it's a bit faster. (Does require you to fire an event or something and passing the stuff through `EventArgs`, but that's quite simple)

Comment: `Dispatcher.Thread` is non-static, so you'd need the instance for the UI thread. As for being faster, I doubt it. From looking at the code I'd bet it is about the same if the control window as been created. If the window has not been created, I'd bet `Control.InvokeRequired` is faster.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend you to put your logic in one method and first check if InvokeRequired then call that method within Invoke otherwise call it directly.

```
if (rssFeedPanel.InvokeRequired) {
    rssFeedPanel.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate 
    { 
        AddLabel();
    }));
}
else AddLabel();
```

And put your logic in AddLabel method:

```
private void AddLabel()
{
    LinkLabel l = new LinkLabel();
    l.Parent = rssFeedPanel;
}
```